# How do i make an abstract class work with JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, abstract

Dear fellow java coders,
I have used an example from http://www.vogella.com/articles/JAXB/article.html

for JAXB XML usage for my 3 classes, UserStorage, User, and UserTest

it works fine, but it's just the unmarchialing of

```
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(UserStorage.class);
                Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
                m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);

the User class is ABSTRACT!, so it throws an
```

> Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: Unable
>   to create an instance of platform.User
>    - with linked exception: [java.lang.InstantiationException]  at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleEvent(UnmarshallingContext.java:648)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:236)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.createInstance(UnmarshallingContext.java:615)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StructureLoader.startElement(StructureLoader.java:170)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext._startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:487)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:465)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.SAXConnector.startElement(SAXConnector.java:135)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:501)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:400)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2756)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:648)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:140)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:511)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:808)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:119)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1205)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:522)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:200)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:173)
>     at
>   javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:137)
>     at
>   javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:194)
>     at platform.UserTest.main(UserTest.java:77) Caused by:
>   java.lang.InstantiationException  at
>   sun.reflect.InstantiationExceptionConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(InstantiationExceptionConstructorAccessorImpl.java:30)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ClassFactory.create0(ClassFactory.java:112)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.createInstance(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:231)     at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.createInstance(UnmarshallingContext.java:609)
>     ... 20 more

Is there any solution for this, so i could bind the User class to the XML, as i can save the XML file with user details, but it's when i want to retrieve it, it conplains that User class is abstract, I have an admin, broker, shareholder sub classes, but so far, in my user test class, i have created only 4 admins to test on, thanks and hope you can help.

```
import platform.UserStorage;
import platform.User;



public class UserTest {

private static final String USER_XML = "user2.xml";

public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException, IOException {

    ArrayList<User> userList = new ArrayList<User>();

    // create test users
            User user1 = new Admin();
            user1.setName("Dave");
            user1.setPass("1234");
            user1.setDeleted(true);
            user1.setBan(false);
            userList.add(user1);

            User user2 = new Admin();
            user2.setName("James");
            user2.setPass("1234");
            user2.setDeleted(true);
            user2.setBan(false);
            userList.add(user2);

            User user3 = new Admin();
            user3.setName("Mike");
            user3.setPass("1234");
            user3.setDeleted(true);
            user3.setBan(false);
            userList.add(user3);


            // create bookstore, assigning book
            UserStorage userstore = new UserStorage();
            userstore.setListName("Test List");
            userstore.setUserList(userList);

            // create JAXB context and instantiate marshaller
            JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(UserStorage.class);
            Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
            m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
            m.marshal(userstore, System.out);

            Writer w = null;
            try {
                w = new FileWriter(USER_XML);
                m.marshal(userstore, w);
            } finally {
                try {
                    w.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }

            // get variables from our xml file, created before
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Output from our XML File: ");
            Unmarshaller um = context.createUnmarshaller();
            UserStorage userstore2 = (UserStorage) um.unmarshal(new FileReader(
                    USER_XML));

            for (int i = 0; i < userstore2.getUsersList().toArray().length; i++) {
                System.out.println("User " + (i + 1) + ": "
                        + userstore2.getUsersList().get(i).getName() + " Pass "
                        + userstore2.getUsersList().get(i).getPass());
            }}  }



package platform;


import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;


//If you want you can define the order in which the fields are written
//Optional

/**
 * @author dinesh.kaushish, james.wyche //updated XML properties.
 * 
 */
@XmlRootElement(name = "user")
@XmlType(propOrder = { "name", "pass", "deleted", "ban" })
```

..

```
public abstract class User implements UserInterface {

private String name;
private String pass;
private boolean deleted;
private boolean ban;

/**
 * @ author dinesh.kaushish
 * @param String username
 * return void
 */

public void setName(String name)
{
    this.name = name;
}

// If you like the variable name, e.g. "name", you can easily change this
    // name for your XML-Output:

/**
 * @author dinesh.kaushish
 * @param null
 * @return String user;
 */
@XmlElement(name = "user")
public String getName()
{
    return this.name;
}

/**
 * @author dinesh.kaushish
 * @param String pwd
 * @return void
 */
public void setPass(String pass)
{
    this.pass=pass;
}

/**
 * @author dinesh.kaushish
 * @param void
 * @return String password
 */
@XmlElement(name = "pass")
public String getPass()
{
    return pass;
}

/**
 * @author dinesh.kaushish
 * @param dFlag
 * @return void
 */
public void setDeleted(boolean deleted)
{
    this.deleted = deleted;
}

/**
 * @author dinesh.kaushish
 * @return boolean isDeleted
 */
@XmlElement(name = "deleted")
public boolean getDeleted()
{
    return deleted;
}


/**
 * @author dinesh.kaushish
 * @param bFlag
 */
public void setBan(boolean ban)
{
    this.ban = ban;
}

/**
 * @author dinesh.kaushish
 * @return Boolean isBanned
 */
@XmlElement(name = "ban")
public Boolean getBan()
{
    return ban;
}


public abstract void addUser();
public abstract void removeUser();
public abstract void verifyUser();
public abstract void passReset();
public abstract void faultReport();
public abstract void RequestsForAccess();
public abstract void UpdateDetails();
public abstract void BanUser();
public abstract void ChangePermissions();


    }



package platform;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.HashMap;

import javax.xml.stream.XMLEventReader;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException;
import javax.xml.stream.events.XMLEvent;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementWrapper;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;





/**
 * @author michael.wambeek, james.wyche //added JAXB support.
 *
 */
//This statement means that class "Bookstore.java" is the root-element of our example
@XmlRootElement(namespace = "platform")
public class UserStorage {

// XmLElementWrapper generates a wrapper element around XML representation
    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "userList")
    // XmlElement sets the name of the entities
    @XmlElement(name = "user")
private ArrayList<User> userList;
private String listName = "";
```

//  private static UserStorage instance; 
    // end of james.wyche JAXB codes.

```
public UserStorage(){

}

/**
 * @author michael.wambeek
 * 
 * Searches for a username and returns the password.
 * 
 * @param username The username to search for
 * @return The password of the correct username or null
 * @throws Exception
 */
public String findUser(String username) throws Exception{
    return search(username);
}

public boolean storeUser(String username, String password, UserType type){
    return true;
}

/**
 * @author james.wyche
 * @param userList
 */
public void setUserList(ArrayList<User> userList) {
    this.userList = userList;
}

/**
 * 
 * @return UserList
 */
public ArrayList<User> getUsersList() {
    return userList;
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Why this is failing is because Jaxb will attempt to create an instance of User. which is abstract and therefore the failure.

On your abstract class add the annotations

```
@XmlTransient //Prevents the mapping of a JavaBean property/type to XML representation
@XmlSeeAlso({Admin.class, <other class>}) //Instructs JAXB to also bind other classes when binding this class
```

see the javadoc for each([XmlTransient](http://jaxb.java.net/nonav/2.2.5/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlTransient.html), [XmlSeeAlso](http://jaxb.java.net/nonav/2.2.5/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSeeAlso.html))

What this will do is prevent jaxb from trying to initialize your abstract class.

The only downside to this method I found is there will be extra namespace information added to the xml that gets created.

Comment: Adding XmlTransient on the super class will remove the inheritance relationship which may not be desired, see:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/search/label/XmlTransient.  The fillowing article may help:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/11/jaxb-and-inheritance-using-xsitype.html

Answer (score 9):

You need to add a [XmlSeeAlso](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSeeAlso.html) annotation to the User class with the attributes Admin and all the other concrete classes that subclass the User class.

```
@XmlSeeAlso({Admin.class})
```

PS, don't forget to add the Xml tag @XmlRootElement to the Admin class.

Comment: Thanks so much Noam, Jan and Sean, I fixed it using your solutions :)

Answer (score 0):

That cannot work, because JAXB has to create new instances (objects) of your classes when unmarshalling the xml. And if a tag from the xml is bound to an abstract class, it just cannot instantiate an object from that class. You either have to make the User class non-abstract or bind the xml tag to a concrete sub-class of User.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the `concrete` type of each element:

```
<user xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="Admin">
    ...
</user>
```