# First steps to JAXB - abstract classes and subtypes

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

so these are my first steps with jaxb.  **//** so i uses XmlSeeAlso already.**
[image]

I have a small class hirarchy of holidays. Some of them should be eastern-based and some are fixed (like new year , and so on)

So i created the above classes.

All in all i have a holidayDB class which is holding a Set holiday;
and should be able to marshall and unmarshall it.

the marshalling works properly in my eyes (shortend):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<holidayDB xmlns:ns2="core.calendar.holiday" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="">
    <holiday xsi:type="fix" day="1" month="FEBRUARY" name="NEW_YEAR"/>
    <holiday xsi:type="var" daysAfterEaster="49" name="PENTECOAST_SUNDAY"/>
</holidayDB>
```

This a subclasses of FixedHoliday and VariableHoliday which should be generated from the xml file in reverse.

But here is the problem. Jaxb tries to instanceiate FixedHoliday oder VariableHoliday which is impossible because this are abstract classes.

Does anybody have a small hint to a jaxb rookie?!

thanks in advance. Java Code on request :)

gretings

//edit:

so here is my Holiday class:

```
@XmlSeeAlso({ FixedHoliday.class, VariableHoliday.class })
public abstract class Holiday {

........

}
```

and here is one extended version als ABSTRACT

```
@XmlType(name = "var")
@XmlRootElement
public abstract class VariableHoliday extends Holiday {

...
@XmlAttribute(name = "daysAfterEaster")
abstract int getDaysAfterEaster();


}
```

Till now there is no implementation which is NOT abstract. jaxb should be generate there non abstract classes from xml

Answer (score 1):

If I remember right you have to use the `@XmlSeeAlso` annotation indicating the concrete implementation of your class. This worked for me a while back with `List` for example.

I've just done a little power search and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10267743/how-do-i-make-an-abstract-class-work-with-jaxb) is a related question.

Answer (score 1):

Annotate abstract class with `@XmlSeeAlso`. Example:

```
@XmlSeeAlso({Dog.class,Cat.class})
class Animal {}
class Dog extends Animal {}
class Cat extends Animal {}
```

More info [here](https://jaxb.java.net/nonav/2.2.4/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSeeAlso.html)